# Creating a secondary reference based on destination sheet

Tags: database, vba, excel

I currently have a dilemma. I have a code here which works perfectly for simple data entry. Simply pop the information in and then click the button on the userform the information gets sent to a mastersheet, as well as 1 or 2 of the other 3 sheets it may need to depending on specific qualifying aspects.

The issue I have here is the mastersheet has a reference which is simply the next number in a sequence. Should the data entered qualify the for ws2 I am wanting it to then generate another reference number which would again be the next number in a sequence (within that sheet only).

Below is my code, is anyone able to assit?

Thanks,

```
Dim mRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim Nextnum As Long
Dim Xnum As Long



Set ws1 = Worksheets("MasterData")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("X")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("A")
Set ws4 = Worksheets("C")

Nextnum = Sheets("MasterData").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Value + 1
'Xnum = Sheets("X").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Value + 1


Dim TargetWorksheets As Variant
'16 qualifying scenarios to determine where the data will be sent

    Select Case True
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtClaimVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws4)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)

        Case Else: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1)
    End Select

For Each ws In TargetWorksheets

'find first empty row in worksheets
    mRow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'copy userform info data to the qualifying database sheets
    ws.Cells(mRow, 1).Value = Nextnum
    ws.Cells(mRow, 2).Value = Format(Date, "DD/MM/YYYY")
    ws.Cells(mRow, 3).Value = Format(Time, "HH:MM:SS")
    ws.Cells(mRow, 4).Value = CInt(Format(Date, "WW"))
    ws.Cells(mRow, 5).Value = Format(Date, "MMM-YY")
    ws.Cells(mRow, 6).Value = CInt(Format(Date, "YYYY"))
    ws.Cells(mRow, 7).Value = 1
    ws.Cells(mRow, 8).Value = TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000)
    ws.Cells(mRow, 9).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBd.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("G:H"), 2, False)
    ws.Cells(mRow, 10).Value = Application.UserName
               If ComboBd.Value = "Mn" Then ws.Cells(mRow, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboCompany.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("L:N"), 2, False) Else
               If ComboBd.Value = "Pur" Then ws.Cells(mRow, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboCompany.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("P:R"), 2, False) Else
                   If ComboBd.Value = "Vog" Then ws.Cells(mRow, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboCom.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("P:R"), 2, False)
    ws.Cells(mRow, 12).Value = Format(Me.TxtRD.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY")
    ws.Cells(mRow, 13).Value = ComboPD.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 14).Value = ComboNP.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 15).Value = ComboBd.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 16).Value = ComboCom.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 17).Value = TxtAdditional.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 18).Value = Format(Me.TxtDD.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY")
    ws.Cells(mRow, 19).Value = TxtBn.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 20).Value = TxtFS.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 21).Value = ComboPr.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 22).Value = ComboIs.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 23).Value = TxtUn.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 24).Value = TxtWt.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 25).Value = TxtIn.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 26).Value = TxtDt.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 27).Value = TxtShp.Value

    Next ws
```

Comment: I can't test this code easily since it is part of a userform with references to Me.TxtRD, etc..., but it appears to me that you want to put a line something like "Nextnum = ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Value + 1" right above "Next ws"

Comment: Hi Tony, the nextnum is already being projected, I want a secondary reference only in the qualifying instances the data gets placed into ws2. Xnum essentially.

Answer (score 0):

How about a function:

```
Function GetNextId(ws As Worksheet, col As Variant) As Long
    GetNextId = WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Columns(col)) + 1
End Function
```

Call it simply like this:

```
Nextnum = GetNextId(Sheets("MasterData"), "A")
' or: Nextnum = GetNextId(Sheets("MasterData"), 1)
Xnum = GetNextId(Sheets("X"), "A"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has not worked. It is still pulling through the Nextnum but does not appear to pull through the Xnum when data is going to ws2.

Comment: But your sheet 'X' contains IDs in col "A"? Is it in the same workbook?

Comment: Yes these are in the same workbook. So I need the reference from col A in mastersheet to come across into sheet X But then in column 29 or "AC" to generate a completely separate reference which will run in sequence

Comment: And you changed the 2nd parameter to "AC" (or 29)?

Comment: Function GetNextId(ws As Worksheet, col As Variant) As Long
    GetNextId = WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Columns(col)) + 1
End Function

Comment: Nextnum = GetNextId(Sheets("MasterData"), "A")
Xnum = GetNextId(Sheets("X"), "AC")

Comment: I don't get it. Even if you are dealing with an complete empty sheet, it should return `1`. Are you eating up exceptions with an `on error resume next`?

Comment: No I haven't used any of that in my code. It is just as mentioned in the original question with that addition as it made perfect sense